# Prove $KN\cong K\times N$ if $K\cap N=\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$, $N$ be normal subgroups in $G$.  I would like to show that if $K\cap N=\{e\}$, then $KN\cong K\times N$.

My original thought was to invoke the first Isomorphism theorem.  Therefore I would have to find an appropriate mapping $\varphi$ whose kernel is $\{e\}$.

In a previous exercise, I showed, again by the first Isomorphism theorem that

$$\frac{KN}{K\cap N}\cong\frac{KN}{N}\times\frac{KN}{K}$$

thus, if $K\cap N=\{e\}, $ i would just have to show that $\frac{KN}{N}=K$ and $\frac{KN}{K}=N$.  Thus my idea was to prove that under the condition that the intersection of $K$ and $N$ that elements in $KN$ can commute freely.  We know that $KN=NK$, but this does not imply commutativity, only that if $kn\in KN$, then $kn=n'k'$ with $n$ not necessarily equal to $n'$ and such with $k$.  I just can't come up with a commutativity proof.

EDIT: I forgot to define $KN=\{kn|k\in K, n\in N\}$.

Comment: The answer below is perfect for the tools you have at this level,  but this also follows directly from the semidirect product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that $KN / N \cong K$, use an isomorphism theorem. Take the map 
$$\varphi : KN \to K, \quad kn \to k$$

To check that this is well-defined, notice that

$$kn = k'n' \iff k'^{-1}k = n'n^{-1} \iff k = k' \text{ and } n' = n$$
It's clearly a homomorphism, and its kernel is exactly $N$.

Comment: I am having trouble with the homomorphism, since you need two elements from $KN$, $k_1n_1, k_2n_2$.  So $\varphi(k_1n_1k_2n_2)=\varphi(k_1k_2'n_1'n_2)=k_1k_2'=...$

Comment: @Iceman Compute the commutator of two elements and you'll find that $kn = nk$ for all $n, k$. For example, $kn(nk)^{-1} = knk^{-1} \cdot n^{-1} \in N$, while $kn(nk)^{-1} = k \cdot nk^{-1}n^{-1} \in K$.